# Code responsible for browsing Firefox's desktop

Tags: firefox, desktop, xul

Where is the code responsible for showing the desktop when you go to a file URL representing a folder in Firefox? Something like the relevant interface or XUL file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implementation is pretty arcane and ancient.

1. file channel handler will [create](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/protocol/file/nsFileChannel.cpp#298) an [`nsDirectoryIndexStream`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/base/src/nsDirectoryIndexStream.cpp). This stream will return a specifically crafted text-only representation of the listing (Try View Source to see how it looks like). The file channel handler also sets a special mime type `APPLICATION_HTTP_INDEX_FORMAT = "application/http-index-format"`
2. Via the [`nsIStreamConverterService`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/streamconv/public/nsIStreamConverterService.idl), a stream converter implemented in [`nsIndexedToHTML`](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/streamconv/converters/nsIndexedToHTML.cpp) will now produce the final output stream doing a `application/http-index-format -> text/html` conversation.
3. Finally, the output html links some style sheet via `chrome://global/skin/dirListing/dirListing.css`, which is in fact part of the [platform specific themes](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/find?string=dirListing.css&tree=mozilla-central&hint=), to give the result a more native-looking appearance.

Comment: Sweet, great answer, thanks! I suppose the best way a humble add-on guy like myself could adapt this would be to listen to page loads and alter the generated HTML source. I think it's a pity though that such important functionality can't be more easily customized/extended--would be nice, for example, if I could receive the list of files and generate source myself. Ah well...thanks again...

Comment: You should also be able to register your own stream converter implementation in the place of nsIndexedToHTML. Of course, you should keep in mind, that this thing also displays some other stuff like ftp listings.